# Как программно изменить размер шрифта во всех фрагментах?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть активити и 200 фрагментов. Как мне сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку, например выбор шрифта, менялся размер текста во всех фрагментах и еще сохранялся выбранный размер после выхода из приложения?

```
final String PREFS_NAME = "PREFS_NAME";    
final String TAG_TEXT_SIZE = "TAG_TEXT_SIZE";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    btnSizeBig = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSB);
    btnSB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            question.setTextSize(getTextSize);
        }
    });

    myPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

}

 public void saveTextSize(int textSize) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPref.edit();
    editor.putString(TAG_TEXT_SIZE, textSize);
    editor.apply();

}

public int getTextSize() {

    return myPref.getInt(TAG_TEXT_SIZE, null);

}

 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentBackground(), "");
    adapter.addFragment(new Question_1(), "");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

## У меня пока что два фрагмента, но их количество будет увеличиваться до двухсот.

Решил проблему следующим образом:

Создал res/xml/preferens

```
<ListPreference
    android:entries="@array/text_size"
    android:entryValues="@array/text_size2"
    android:key="list3"
    android:summary="Выберите размер текста"
    android:title="Размер текста">
</ListPreference>
```

И в каждом фрагменте установил в onResume

```
public void onResume() {

    String listValue = SP.getString("list3", "20");
    question_text.setTextSize(Float.parseFloat(listValue));
    question.setTextSize(Float.parseFloat(listValue));
    answer.setTextSize(Float.parseFloat(listValue));
    answer_text.setTextSize(Float.parseFloat(listValue));
    super.onResume();
```

Где list3 это возврат значений, 20, 30, 40, а "20", это размер текста по умолчанию пока не будет выбран один из трех вариантов в настройках. 
String listValue = SP.getString("list3", "20");

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете создать несколько тем:

**res/values/attr.xml**

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="Theme.MyApp">
        <attr name="myTextSize" format="dimension|reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**res/values/theme.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
        <item name="myTextSize">16sp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.MyApp.Small">
        <item name="myTextSize">10sp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.MyApp.Normal">
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.MyApp.Large">
        <item name="myTextSize">22sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textSize">?myTextSize</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Магия заключается в подмене темы для фрагмента:

**MyFragment.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int themeId = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()).getInt("theme", R.style.Theme_MyApp_Normal);
    final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(),themeId);
    inflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    return v;
}
```

В активити по клику на кнопках или в тулбаре или в любом другом месте меняем текущую тему в настройках:

**MyActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.small_theme:
            changeTheme(R.style.Theme_MyApp_Small);
            break;
        case R.id.normal_theme:
            changeTheme(R.style.Theme_MyApp_Normal);
            break;
        case R.id.large_theme:
            changeTheme(R.style.Theme_MyApp_Large);
            break;
    }
}

private void changeTheme(@StyleRes int themeId){
    PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext())
        .edit()
        .putInt("theme", themeId)
        .apply();
    // Обновляем фрагменты
    // Не забываем перекрыть в адаптере getItemPosition,
    // вернув в нем POSITION_NONE
    mViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

При старте приложения в первый раз, перед тем, как загрузятся фрагменты, занесите *default* значение в `SharedPreferences`, после чего когда делаете `inflate` для `View` во фрагментах, устанавливаете размер их шрифта равным значению, взятому из `SharedPreferences`. Далее, когда пользователь меняет в настройках размер шрифта, перезаписывайте *default* значение `textSize` в `SharedPreferences`.

Пример:

```
final String PREFS_NAME = "PREFS_NAME";
final String TAG_TEXT_SIZE = "TAG_TEXT_SIZE";

mPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

public void saveTextSize(int textSize){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPref.edit();
    editor.putInt(TAG_TEXT_SIZE,textSize);
    editor.apply();
}
public int getTextSize(){
    return mPref.getInt(TAG_TEXT_SIZE , null);
}
```

Таким образом вы можете записать и считать значения. Далее вы просто устанавливаете значение `textView.setTextSize(getTextSize())`.

По поводу обновления размера текста в фрагментах, коротко:

В `ViewPagerAdapter` добавляете этот метод:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
   return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

После этого вызываете `yourPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Вот [ответ на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18088509/5634351), в котором описан этот вариант и ещё один. Если вам интересно, то можете там посмотреть.

Повторю, что вы должны в фрагментах устанавливать значение, взятое из `SharedPreferences`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //inflate views 
    // ...
    mPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    int defaultTextSize = 22; //for example
    int textSize = mPref.getInt(TAG_TEXT_SIZE , defaultTextSize);
    textView.setTextSize(textSize);
}
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь, я более зеленый в этом деле чем аватар, который подобрала система. 

Возникли такие вопросы:

mPref = MyApplication.getContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0); - при вводе MyApplication АС ругается, также я попытался ввести MainActivity, но тогда ругается _getContext_


 _PREFS_NAME_ и _TAG_TEXT_SIZE_ это константы ? В строке _editor.putString_, АС ругается на букву _s_ за запятой, и предлагает ввести на _saveTextSize_. И еще вопрос, это все я прописываю в главном активити, который уже сам будет задавать размер текста во всех фрагментах, правильно я понял?

Comment: Да вы можете это описать в главном активити, главное что  бы до того момента когда начнут подгружаться фрагменты у вас уже было записано нужное значение в SharedPreferences. Я обновил ответ, попробуйте!

Comment: извиняюсь еще раз, у меня **textSize** и **null** выделены красным, все остальное нормально. У меня такой метод изменения размера текста: 

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.text_big) {
            question_text.setTextSize(40f, saveTextSize(textSize));
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

При таком воде, **textSize** также выделяется красным, поясните пожалуйста, как именно задать размеры, чтобы они сохранились.

Comment: АС предложило заменить
         
`editor.putString(TAG_TEXT_SIZE, String.valueOf(textSize));`

`return myPref.getInt(TAG_TEXT_SIZE, Integer.parseInt(null));`

Comment: наверное это просто опечатка, но метод `setText()` устанавливает сам текст, а не размер текста.

Comment: @pavlofff, я заменил на setTextSize, и получил в нем метод getTextSize, как указал Kirill, теперь осталось понять, как использовать метод saveTextSize, и если вы мне вкраце объясните как это все работает, и каким образом размер текста будет установлен во всех 200 фрагментах, вы будете гангстерами кодинга в моих глазах)), ну хотя вы и так таковыми являетесь в моих глазах)

Comment: Пардон за ошибки в коде, я подправил. Может мы вам и поможем, если вы покажите свой код, не зная вашей реализации - мы можем только гадать.

Comment: @KirillStoianov, даже не знаю какую именно часть кода вам показать, у меня в главном активити **ViewPager**, 

`private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment_1(), "");
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment_2(), "");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }` - и таких фрагментов будет 200. 

В каждом фрагменте 3 **TextView**, размер текста которых будет **нормальный, средний, большой**? простите, я не знаю как тут делать отступы в тексте, каша

Comment: @Int404 Обновил ответ

Comment: @KirillStoianov, добавил код к вопросу

Comment: в целом я уже понял, попробуйте сделать так как я написал.